# Is $f-nf$ zero on $G$ for some $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a divisible group, $H$ a group and $f:G\to H$ be a homomorphism. Let $n$ be a positive integer. Is $f-nf$ zero on $G$?

Comment: Of course not! Try to think about it. Already the special case $f=\mathrm{id}$ fails.

Comment: $G$ need not to be $H$.

Comment: I think $n=1$ makes the identity work...